# How do I use RunCode to run a function?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have written a function to run from a macro using `RunCode`.

I am trying to call the function from the `OnClick` event of a command button.

I want to print a different page of my report depending upon the value in the text control `Text28`.

When I press the button, the function is not running.

```
Public Function PrintOut()
    If Text28 = "aaa" Then
        DoCmd.PrintOut acPages, 2, 2, , 1
    ElseIf Text28 = "bbb" Then
        DoCmd.PrintOut acPages, 3, 3, , 1
    ElseIf Text28 = "ccc" Then
        DoCmd.PrintOut acPages, 4, 4, , 1
    ElseIf Text28 = "ddd" Then
        DoCmd.PrintOut acPages, 5, 5, , 1
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: It's seem a bit odd to me that it runs and there is no error message in all this. If you add in a random `MsgBox` in your code does it get executed? If so then, the issue might be with the `Text28` conditional statement.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a Macro with a `RunCode` action to evaluate your function, I would suggest evaluating the code directly from a VBA event handler associated with the `OnClick` event for your button, e.g. (changing the `Command0` to suit your button name):

```vb
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    If Text28 = "aaa" Then
        DoCmd.PrintOut acPages, 2, 2, , 1
    ElseIf Text28 = "bbb" Then
        DoCmd.PrintOut acPages, 3, 3, , 1
    ElseIf Text28 = "ccc" Then
        DoCmd.PrintOut acPages, 4, 4, , 1
    ElseIf Text28 = "ddd" Then
        DoCmd.PrintOut acPages, 5, 5, , 1
    End If
End Sub
```

A `Select Case` statement may also be more appropriate than sequential `if` statements, e.g.:

```vb
Private Sub Command0_Click()
    Select Case Text28
        Case "aaa": DoCmd.PrintOut acPages, 2, 2, , 1
        Case "bbb": DoCmd.PrintOut acPages, 3, 3, , 1
        Case "ccc": DoCmd.PrintOut acPages, 4, 4, , 1
        Case "ddd": DoCmd.PrintOut acPages, 5, 5, , 1
        Case Else: MsgBox "Text28 has an invalid value."
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: The reason that I would like to build it into the OnClick macro for the button is that there are already a couple of actions that are in the macro, so I was trying to find a way to just add to it. I can convert the macro to VBA code, but I, being an Access novice, get confused by everything that is in the code window and I don't know where to put my If or Select Case actions.

Comment: If you wish to remain using a macro, providing that your function is defined within a public module then you should be able to invoke the function successfully from the macro. If this approach isn't producing any errors, but also isn't performing any actions, I would suggest ensuring that your function has a 'default branch' to the conditional statement, e.g. a final `Else` in your sequence of `If` statements, or the `Case Else` as shown in my `Select Case` example - this allows you to verify that at least one condition is being met.